# Improve way of displaying site generated error messages

Tags: feature-request, design, error-message

After using Stack Overflow for a while, I have noticed that some error messages are just displayed using no formatting in a completely empty page (see example below):

[image]

Wouldn't be better to actually display the error in a more friendlier way? Maybe to use an `AJAX` call to make the validation when submitting the edit (or any other similar action).

Also, error page contains no navigation options and user is forced to use browser's `Back` button.

Shortly put, **I would like to display error messages in the normal site layout.**

Comment: Idk what SOF is